# How to lock the same object twice with Hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, locking

I do consequently retrieve the same object from DB. Both times with DB-level locking. All within single session/transaction.

```
funk()
funk()

def funk() {
    def account = Account.withCriteria {
        id 123
        lock true
        lockMode LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT
    }
    account.save()
}
```

The problem: the second retrieval hangs reading a HTTP socket forever.

Is it possible to solve the problem without redesigning the code much?

- Maybe via manual unlocking
- or via re-entrant locking
- or I could just skip locking if I could know it is locked already...

Grails 2.2.0, some Hibernate, Oracle XE

Comment: What happens if you do account.save(flush:true)?